# How can I prioritize a SPARQL query to query for one thing, before querying another?

Tags: sparql, wikipedia-api

The query below simply goes to Wikipedia and grabs famous people born with the date given.  I want the query to first prioritize famous people born in the USA first, then the UK, and then everyone else. This will eventually be for a website whose traffic demographics will be from those countries mainly.

USA = wd:Q6156
Great Britain = wd:Q1833

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?image ?birthdate ?description WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
          wdt:P569 ?birthdate.
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P18 ?image. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person schema:description ?description. FILTER(LANG(?description) = "en") }
  FILTER(?birthdate = "${formattedDate}"^^xsd:dateTime)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
LIMIT 30
```

I tried this

```
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?image ?birthdate ?description WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
          wdt:P569 ?birthdate;
          wdt:P27 wd:Q30.
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P18 ?image. }
  OPTIONAL { ?person schema:description ?description. FILTER(LANG(?description) = "en") }
  FILTER(?birthdate = "${formattedDate}"^^xsd:dateTime)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }

  FILTER (?birthPlace = wd:Q6156) UNION
  FILTER (?birthPlace = wd:Q1833) UNION
  ?person
}
LIMIT 30
```

but the query is somehow malformed.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't get what the second query is supposed to do? The variable `?birthPlace` isn't bound to any value as it has been never used in a triple pattern. So where is `?person wdt:P19 ?birthPlace .` ? The query also doesn't reflect what you said in your question, first US, the UK, then the rest. Why then a filter on German places? `Q6156` is obviously not USA, I'm wondering why you think so given that you already used `Q30`. Did you copy/paste from different places without checking the entity URIs?

Comment: Also, are there persons in Wikidata with US citizenship and birth place somewhere in Germany?

Comment: `SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?image ?birthdate ?personDescription WHERE {
  {
    ?person wdt:P27 wd:Q30.
    BIND(0  AS ?priority)
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?person wdt:P27 wd:Q145.
    BIND(1  AS ?priority)
  }
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
    wdt:P569 ?birthdate.
  OPTIONAL { ?person wdt:P18 ?image. }
  FILTER(?birthdate = "1945-07-20T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ?priority
LIMIT 100` - it get's people from USA and UK, then orders by some priority value. You can see that the last two people are from UK

Comment: Yes @UninformedUser, I actually got this from chatGPT.  It appears chatGPT led me astray with the German code Q6156. What you provided works great.  You should post it as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: yep, ChatGPT is great, but experiments already showed that finding the current Wikidata entities doesn't work in most cases. A workaround is to search for the Wikidata IDs before via a separate service, then inject those into the prompt as context.

Comment: If you want, feel free to provide the working query as an answer and accept it. Maybe you can also add one or two sentences about the issue you had with ChatGPT (in year 2023) and how the query performs w.r.t. runtime. Cheers